# Strengthening the second isomorphism theorem for topological groups

Tags: topological-groups

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448303/a-counter-example-of-the-second-isomorphism-theorem-for-topological-groups) I asked about the following version of the second isomorphism theorem for topological groups -I implicitly assume that every subgroup inherits the subspace topology-:

> Let $G$ be a topological group and $H$ and $N$ subgroups. If $H$ is contained in the normalizer of $N$, there is a canonical continuous isomorphism
>   $$\phi:\frac{H}{H\cap N}\rightarrow \frac{HN}{N}$$

In general we cannot guarantee that this $\phi$ is an homeomorphism. However, this is due to the fact that the continuos homomorphism
$$H\rightarrow \frac{HN}{N}\text{,}$$
given by $h\mapsto hN$, cannot be guarantee to be open, close or and identification. And thus the first isomorphism theorem for topological groups does not give a homeomoprhism. Obviously when $H$ is open everything works nicely and we obtain a homeomorphism, are there more general (sufficient or necessary) conditions (on $H$ and $N$?) to guarantee that the previous map is open, closed or an identification?

Comment: If $G$ is Hausdorff, $N$ is closed and $H$ is compact, then $HN/N$ is Hausdorff and thus $\phi$ is closed, because a closed subset of $H$ is compact, the continuous image of a compact set is compact, and in a Hausdorff space a compact set is closed.