# is $t: \frac{U}{U\cap V}\to \frac{UV}{V}$ not a homeomorphism of topological groups in gerneral?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

If U and V are topological subgroups of a topological group G, such that G=UV, and V normal in G, we know that the map $t: \frac{U}{U\cap V}\to \frac{UV}{V}, x(U\cap V)\mapsto xV$ is a isomorphism of groups. But this map is not a homeomorphism in general, right? Does anybody have a counterexample? Which properties for U and V we need such that t is a an open map? I would imagine, if you consider $f:U\to \frac{UV}{V}, x\mapsto  xV$ continuous homormophism of top. groups,  $\pi_{U\cap V}:U\to \frac{U}{U\cap V}, x\mapsto x(U\cap V)$ surjective continuous quotientmap, s.t. $t\circ \pi_{U\cap V}=f$, in the case that f is open (that isn't true in general), then t has to be open? Best.

Comment: Not sure the tag `algebraic-topology` is valid here (which usually refers to algebraic invariants of topological spaces like homotopy or homology groups). Not sure it's invalid, either.

Comment: Ok, I remove the tag. Regards

Comment: Could you clarify "in general"? As in what is the condition you are dropping in saying so? I presume it's the normality of $V$ you wish to omit. Already, there isn't any normality condition on U. Then UV is probably not even a subgroup! This hopefully (and probably) would throw the door open to counterexamples!

Comment: I do not understand the question as stated: What quotient are you taking, left or right? Whatever the quotient is, without normality assumption, the quotient is not a group, what do you mean by an isomorphism then? Are you assuming that both U and V are normal?

Comment: $t$ is open if and only if $f$ is open. $f$ is open if and only if for every neighbourhood $W$ of $e$ in $G$, the set $(W\cap U)\cdot V$ is a neighbourhood of $e$ in $G$. There must be a better characterisation, but I don't see it now.

Comment: i have edited my post a littlebit, V has to be a normal subgroup of G ( so V is normal in UV).  With "t is an isomorphism" that means t is an isomorphism of groups. I want something like an isomorphism theorem for topological groups and i'm searching for conditions (like compactness or something like this for U and V) such that i) t is open and ii) t is a homeomorphism . In this case it is G=UV, I dont know how important it is.

Comment: Yesterday a few hours later I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448303/a-counter-example-of-the-second-isomorphism-theorem-for-topological-groups