# Second isomorphism theorem for homogeneous spaces

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, topological-groups

So if a Lie group $G$ acts transitively on a manifold $X$, then $X$ is diffeomorphic to the quotient $G/H$ where $H$ is the  stabilizer subgroup  of a point $x$ in $X$.

Now if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $N\cdot x\cong N/(N\cap H)$.

Can we imitate the  second isomorphism theorem, i.e, is it true that $N/(N\cap H) \cong NH/H$ as manifolds?

Comment: Not necessarily. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448303/a-counter-example-of-the-second-isomorphism-theorem-for-topological-groups